# Best and cheapest way to store users data

Tags: java, android, storage, backend

I have an app out in the market and planning to maintain basic user data somewhere on backend.
My app is free so I am NOT getting any money from users.
My question is what is the best way to store this data(data has name, email, phonenumber etc.)
One option is to use Google Mobile Backend starter kit but that seems too complex for such a small requirement.
Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Guys I know this question is subjective but this is something that everyone wants to know, so if you cant answer it dont vote for close as we may get a constructive discussion as an answer to this question.

Comment: Do you want to store this data in some centralized database on your server or only on the phone

Comment: In fact the question is quite subjective: I would use a very simple php application that receives a json with user data and stores it in a mysql DB .. if you are confident about using php I can give you abundant information about

Comment: I want to store it on the back-end, so that I can run some queries on my user data when needed. I can use anything but I am mostly concerned about the cost of maintaining this data.

Comment: @Manan just setup web-host at one of many free providers and create an API in php or any other server side language it is very easy to setup and access database such a way.

Comment: @Setu can you provide some names that provide free hosting with some data storage, do that have any limit on number of requests/sec?

Comment: "can you provide some names that provide free hosting with some data storage" -- asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic on Stack Overflow nowadays. Beyond that, this is subjective, because "best" is only something *you* can answer, because only you know what "best" means to you. "this is something that everyone wants to know" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly?

Comment: edit: remove comment as I really don't want to be supporting one service over another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are many options you can achieve your goal and these options depends on your proficiency in other areas apart from java and your preferences. Below is just a small list,

Server side language: `php`, `jsp`, etc

Database: `MySQL`, `NoSQL`, `SQLite`, etc

Webhost: any free provider (just google "Free webhosting service")

Client side: as you mentioned you already have an app on play store so you will have to update you application accordingly and release new version.

I prefer to use combination of `php` and `MySQL` for all my back end work as I feel it is very easy to create and maintain. I also use 000webhost.com as free webhosting service, this service is completely free and also supports `php` and `MySql` without any restriction.

First Step I would suggest you is to choose your web-hosting provider, sign up on it and setup your database through `PHPMyAdmin` (Very easy to do so if you know basic database fundamentals).

Second step would be to create an API according to your choice of server side language (I am assuming you would use `php` but you are free to use any other language). If you don't know any server side language then you might want to follow some online tutorial and get your self familiar with `php` (which is again very easy of you know some other programming language). You can simply start from coding basic functions such as retrieving all data and `echo` them on browser or `insert` some fields in database, etc. I would advice you to completely code and test all your functionality on normal web browser before you go on about updating you android application and the reason is that once you know what response you are expecting and you have tested it on computer screen it becomes easy to code it for android.

And the final step would be to update your android application, for this well know process is using `json` strings for sending and/or retrieving data to/from database. If you are only looking to insert few fields in database then you can also use `GET` or `POST` methods to send and receive data. And the good news is there are many great tutorials available online for `HttpRequest` from android you can google it yourself.

**Disclaimer: I am not promoting any free/paid service provider in my answer, the only reason I mentioned name is because OP has asked twice for it. If you are thinking of downvoting or flagging the answer for that reason please leave comment and I would delete it ASAP.**

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple php page that captures user data via json from Android and saves them in a MySQL db (technology simple and very cheap, there are many hosting php + mysql free or very low cost);

but if you prefer a java-oriented approach, although slightly more complex

I advise you to Google App Engine that is free (with well-defined limits):

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html

using the latter you will need to use servlets (do not recommend endpoints) and use JPA to access the database which provides GAE (NoSQL database)